# Концептуальный вопрос по SPA на React

Tags: html, reactjs, дизайн, spa

Как правильно (общепринято) делать SPA на React - собрать один большой
React-компонент (из многих маленьких компонентов ) и рендерить его
в `<div id="root"></div>`  или же возможно часть (малоизменяемую или неизменяюмую - к примеру какую нибудь шапку) традиционно на  HTML , a React - компоненты использовать только в тех частях где требует SPA?
И возможно аргументы за и против обоих подходов.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от функционала. Если все на странице требует динамики, например в той же шапке отображаются результаты действий, или в ней присутствуют компоненты типа юзер-профайла, или состав меню зависит от роли и т.д., то есть смысл все сразу делать на реакте, загружая приложение в корневой див.

Если же элементы шапки и подвала действительно статичны, а вся работа делается в некотором воркспейсе между ними, то стоит оставить их статичными.

Основной плюс статичных шапки и подвала: при сбое в работе приложения пользователь все равно увидит шапку с некими действиями (например перезагрузить) или подвал с адресом/телефоном, куда сообщить. В другом случае, при сбое приложения, пользователь увидит просто белый экран.

Comment: да именно такой вариант шапка и подвал как бы чисто оформительские функции - а динамика между ними